# Custom background color for BottomNavigationView from attribute

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

selector for `itemTextColor`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/NavigationBarColorTextDefault" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="?attr/NavigationBarColorTextActive" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="?attr/NavigationBarColorTextDefault" />
</selector>
```

Selector for `itemBackground`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/NavigationBarColorBackgroundDefault" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="?attr/NavigationBarColorBackgroundActive" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="?attr/NavigationBarColorBackgroundDefault" />
</selector>
```

For `itemTextColor` all fine, but when tried inflate `itemBackground` - fail.
But if change color from attribute to "static" color - it's work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/NavigationBarColorBackgroundDefault" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/NavigationBarColorBackgroundActive" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/NavigationBarColorBackgroundDefault" />
</selector>
```

How to use color from attribute in selector for `itemBackground` or this is impossbile?

Comment: try to change `android:drawable` to `android:color` in the selector.In any case `itemBackground` should be a `drawable`

Comment: tried - doesnt work